# How can I lazy load relation in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have a project where I am using Entity Framework 6 and ASP.NET MVC 5.

I have a need to use lazy loading instead of eager. In other words, I want to be able to access a relation/child after the parent model have been retrieved without using `.Include()`

Here is my simple use case

```
public ActionResult Test(int id)
{
    using(var conn = new MyAppContent())
    {
        var user = conn.User.Where(u => u.Id == id).First();

        var capsule = new SomeWrapper(user)

        return View(capsule);
   }
}
```

This is my `SomeWrapper` class in a nutshell. (I removed most of the code for the sake of simplicity.)

```
public SomeWrapper
{
    public User MyUser { get; set; }
    public SomeWrapper(User user)
    {
        MyUser = user;
    }
    // Of course this class does more than this.
}
```

Here is my `User` Model

```
public User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TimeZone")]
    public int? TimeZoneId { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to know the user's time zone from the view. So I did something like this

```
@model App.SomeWrapper
<p>Model.MyUser.Username<p>
<p>Model.MyUser.TimeZone.Name<p>
```

However, when trying to access the TimeZone.Name I get the following error

```
{"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."}
```

I am not sure how it is disposed? I return `View()` within my `using(){}` block. so it should be disposed after I access it.

I can switch to eager loading "code below" to solve the problem, but I want to know how to do the same thing using lazy loading.

```
public ActionResult Test(int id)
{
    using(var conn = new MyAppContent())
    {
        var user = conn.User.Where(u => u.Id == id).Include(x => x.TimeZone).First();

        var capsule = new SomeWrapper(user)

        return View(capsule);
   }
}
```

How can I lazy load the `TimeZone` relation correctly?

Comment: Lazy loading would more likely cause you a lot of troubles than solving. But anyway, assuming your entity is eligible for lazy loading and lazy loading of the db context is not disabled, to make it work just don't dispose the db context used to retrieve it (remove the `using` block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not access `MyUser.TimeZone` inside `SomeWrapper`.

What you did back there is ***shallow copy*** User to MyUser, and mixing ***Domain Model*** *(some call Entity Model)* and ***View Model***. It is not a good practice as Domain Model should never be exposed to public.

You should not shallow copy from ***Domain Model*** to ***View Model***. Instead, you want deep copy using object-object mapper such as [AutoMapper](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Mapper/AutoMapperConfiguration.cs#L36).

### Lazy Loading

Entity Framework already provides lazy loading, but you ***cannot dispose DbContext*** right after retrieving data.

Instead, you'll need to inject MyAppContent using IoC container such as Autofac, Ninject.

*For example,*

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyAppContent _myAppContent;

    public MyController(MyAppContent myAppContent)
    {
        _myAppContent = myAppContent;
    }

    public ActionResult Test(int id)
    {
        var user = _myAppContent.User.Where(u => u.Id == id).First();

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will the dependency inject create the new instance of context when the controller in constructed automatically? And when/how do I dispose `MyAppContent`?

Comment: You can configure it when you register dependencies in IoC container. We normally register DbContext as transient life-time *which is basically per http request*. For example. [here](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Infrastructure/DependencyManagement/DependencyRegistrar.cs#L61).

Comment: Does that mean I won't have to manually dispose it? will it get disposed automatically at the end of the http request?

Comment: You are correct. ***Register, Resolve and Release*** is the three main responsibilities of IoC container. If you want to know more, I highly recommend [Dependency Injection in .NET by Mark Seemann](https://www.amazon.com/Dependency-Injection-NET-Mark-Seemann/dp/1935182501/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1491332143&sr=8-1&keywords=dependency+injection+in+.net)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your context should be request-scoped. By using `using` in your action, it's scoped much less than that, and in particular is unavailable during the rendering of the view. Note that the fact that the return is inside is inconsequential; the view rendering can happen outside the action-scope.

Long and short, you just need to ensure you have a context that will survive the length of the request. The easiest way to do that is to inject it into your controller using a dependency injection container, and setting it to be request-scoped. If you don't want to go that far, simply make it an ivar on your controller (which by nature is request-scoped). You should also remember to override `Dispose` on your controller, in that case, to dispose of the context properly:

```
private readonly MyAppContent conn = new MyAppContent();

// other controller code

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        conn.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: If I have some action methods that don't use the connection, will injecting the context in the controller cost me extra/unneeded connections when these actions are called?

Comment: No. Creating the context does not actually open any connections. This occurs later when the context must perform an atomic process (i.e. something that actually requires the connection).

Comment: Thank you. Once more thing, Assume I have a custom base controller which inherits the Controller class like so `MyBaseController : Controller`, and in `MyBaseController` I inject `MyAppContent` via the constructor and I add the `Dispose` method you mentioned in your answer. In my child controller `TasksController : MyBaseController`, will I have to call the base() constructor to initialize `MyAppContent` in the new child controller or no?

Comment: Well, no. However, there's a few weird things here. First, if the context is injected, then the controller no longer owns it. Whatever created the context is the owner. Therefore, your controller *should not* dispose of the context, as it doesn't own it. Second, if you need the context in derived classes, then simply make the ivar `protected` rather than `private`. Assuming you do this, then no, you do not need to have a custom ctor for your derived controller.